# Make Docker on Windows use multiple NUMA nodes

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have run into difficulty in using Docker on a Threadripper 3990X. Despite launching 64 containers, each with the `--cpus 2` option passed to `docker run`, I cannot get Docker to use both of the NUMA nodes in that CPU. It always uses node 0. My understanding is that `--cpus 2` should map to two threads or one core. So with 64 containers, I should be able to saturate my CPU, but no matter what, only NUMA node 0 is saturated. This is on Windows 10 Enterprise.

**EDIT 1:** I'm using Windows containers and the guest OS is also Windows (same version as the host).

I've tried `--cpuset-cpus` and `--cpuset-mems` but I get errors saying that Docker for Windows does not support these options. I've tried `start /NODE <NUMA_node> docker run` but that had no effect on which NUMA node the VM runs on. The only bit of success I've had was using `--isolation process` as that exposes all of the cores. However, the nature of the app that I'm containerising means that I really want to switch back to Hyper-V isolation mode.

Comment: I confirmed my HBv4 44 core issue is not the case, it works great: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/409

Answer (score 0):

Reading [KEP-1769: Memory Manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-node/1769-memory-manager##implementation-history) as an example of [Non-uniform memory access (NUMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) usage, there is:

- no support for Windows
- even "[the Linux kernel does not support multi-NUMA memory allocation (pinning)](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-node/1769-memory-manager#how-to-enable-the-guaranteed-memory-allocation-over-many-numa-nodes)"

You could try your containers in a [WSL2 environment](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/wsl/), but that might not be possible if you depend exclusively on a Windows kernel (which explains your Windows containers).

Comment: WSL2 is for linux, but we're using windows containers, the base image is: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

Comment: @flysha Agreed. The gist of this answer is to say: "multiple NUMA nodes does not seem to be supported for Windows Docker images".

Comment: @flysha Do you have a `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` file? If yes, what is its content?